# What do the eigenvalues/vectors of a metric describe?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, metric-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

Given a finite metric space $(X = \{ x_i \}_{i=1}^n,d)$, one can form the matrix $A$ of pairwise distances $a_{ij} = d(x_i, x_j)$.

What does the eigenspectrum of this matrix say about the metric $d$? Considering the success of spectral methods for analyzing various matrices formed from graphs, this seems like a natural thing to do. If it is a thing, what is it called and where should I look for more information?

Comment: If I understand correctly, in a graph, the matrix $A$ contains the shortest path lengths between the nodes?

Comment: There are many different matrices formed from graphs. Even just taking the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix gives you some deep theorems, with more complicated techniques using the graph Laplacian and other related ideas. I have not seen anyone use the shortest path matrix, though.

Comment: However, I should emphasize that in this question I do not care about graphs per se.

Comment: Sorry, I am really not an expert but (if I remember correctly) I have recently heard something similar in connection with mean-field theory.

Comment: Roughly speaking, you can use eigenvalues and eigenvectors to construct for example, Radial Basis functions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function

This can be useful for solving PDE's for example, when you have some non-standard discretization of your space.

Comment: I'm sorry, @AlexR., but I don't see what this has to do with my question. How does solving a PDE give me information about a metric? Do PDEs even make sense for arbitrary metric spaces?

Comment: I feel this matrix is nothing but a weighted adjacency matrix of a complete graph and we could get the interpretation by modifying the existing ideas about adjacency matrices.

Comment: Here it is : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113000/spectrum-of-adjacency-matrix-of-complete-graph?rq=1

Comment: But the weights satisfy the triangle inequality. You certainly cannot get any information about the metric without using the defining property of a metric. Do you know of a spectral graph theory for such graphs? This does not appear to be covered by the field of "metric graph theory."